# Find correct width of divs in jQuery, before content render

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having problems because the width of a `div` is not what I expect it to be on `document.ready`.

The content of `div.left` is rendered dynamically after load, but I need to know the width of `div.right` before then (it contains a D3 graph and I need to know the width in order to set the width of the SVG).

```
<div class="left">
  <span class="left-inner">&nbsp;</span>
</div>
<div class="right">
</div>
```

This is my CSS (set up so that the left div is fixed-width and the right div expands to fill the space available):

```
.left {
  float: left; 
  width: 200px; 
  min-width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
.right { 
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

However, if I run this on `document.ready`:

```
console.log('width', $(".left-inner").width());
```

It says the width is 4px, not 200px as I would expect (and as I need) it to be.

I need to calculate the width of the right div for a separate D3 calculation:

```
console.log('width', $(".right-inner").width());
```

Currently this is 196px wider than it should be.

Why is this happening? How can I get the correct width for the right div? (I guess as a hack I could look up the CSS max-width property for the left div and subtract it from the rendered width of the right div, but I'd rather find a nicer solution.)

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/WVhDL/1/

Comment: The width of a span containing `&nbsp;` should be ~4px.

Comment: Span is inline-block, see setting it as block: http://jsfiddle.net/WVhDL/2/ Or use a DIV as it seems you should http://jsfiddle.net/WVhDL/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.left-inner is a span element and has no width, it is an "inline" element.

add to your css code this, to make it to an block element, or replace "span" with "div"

```
.left-inner {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank goodness for you and for StackOverflow! NB it seems the `&nbsp` is required too.